# Calculating the mean of values from certain cells of a dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a .csv file that contains the power consumed by a machine over a month long period. The file contains 4 readings per hour, so for a 24 hour period there are 96 values, then the next day starts. So to get the value for every Monday at 12:00:00AM the rows will be 96*7 = 672 rows apart. I want to get the mean for each time pertaining to a specific day of the week, such as Mondays at 12:00:00AM, and then save this to a dataframe for the average Monday. The code I have seems to work correctly but I know there's a faster way to do this with a loop but I can't figure it out.

'''
Python:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import statistics
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
per_day = 96;
per = per_day*7
n = len(df);
number_of_days = n / per_day;

day1 = pd.DataFrame()

day1_1200_am = df.loc[0:n:per]
day1 = day1.append(day1_1200_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1215_am = (df.loc[1:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1215_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1230_am = (df.loc[2:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1230_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1245_am = (df.loc[3:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1245_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0100_am = (df.loc[4:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0100_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0115_am = (df.loc[5:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0115_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0130_am = (df.loc[6:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0130_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0145_am = (df.loc[7:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0145_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0200_am = (df.loc[8:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0200_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0215_am = (df.loc[9:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0215_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0230_am = (df.loc[10:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0230_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0245_am = (df.loc[11:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0245_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0300_am = (df.loc[12:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0200_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0315_am = (df.loc[13:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0315_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0330_am = (df.loc[14:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0330_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0345_am = (df.loc[15:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0345_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0400_am = (df.loc[16:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0400_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0415_am = (df.loc[17:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0415_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0430_am = (df.loc[18:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0430_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0445_am = (df.loc[19:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0445_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0500_am = (df.loc[20:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0500_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0515_am = (df.loc[21:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0515_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0530_am = (df.loc[22:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0530_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0545_am = (df.loc[23:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0545_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0600_am = (df.loc[24:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0600_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0615_am = (df.loc[25:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0615_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0630_am = (df.loc[26:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0630_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0645_am = (df.loc[27:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0645_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0700_am = (df.loc[28:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0700_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0715_am = (df.loc[29:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0715_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0730_am = (df.loc[30:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0730_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0745_am = (df.loc[31:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0745_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0800_am = (df.loc[32:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0800_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0815_am = (df.loc[33:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0815_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0830_am = (df.loc[34:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0830_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0845_am = (df.loc[35:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0845_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0900_am = (df.loc[36:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0900_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0915_am = (df.loc[37:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0915_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0930_am = (df.loc[38:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0930_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0945_am = (df.loc[39:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0945_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1000_am = (df.loc[40:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1000_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1015_am = (df.loc[41:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1015_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1030_am = (df.loc[42:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1030_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1045_am = (df.loc[43:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1045_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1100_am = (df.loc[44:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1100_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1115_am = (df.loc[45:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1115_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1130_am = (df.loc[46:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1130_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1145_am = (df.loc[47:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1145_am.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1200_pm = df.loc[48:n:per]
day1 = day1.append(day1_1200_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1215_pm = (df.loc[49:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1215_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1230_pm = (df.loc[50:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1230_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1245_pm = (df.loc[51:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1245_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0100_pm = (df.loc[52:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0100_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0115_pm = (df.loc[53:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0115_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0130_pm = (df.loc[54:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0130_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0145_pm = (df.loc[55:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0145_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0200_pm = (df.loc[56:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0200_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0215_pm = (df.loc[57:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0215_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0230_pm = (df.loc[58:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0230_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0245_pm = (df.loc[59:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0245_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0300_pm = (df.loc[60:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0200_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0315_pm = (df.loc[61:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0315_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0330_pm = (df.loc[62:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0330_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0345_pm = (df.loc[63:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0345_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0400_pm = (df.loc[64:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0400_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0415_pm = (df.loc[65:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0415_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0430_pm = (df.loc[66:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0430_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0445_pm = (df.loc[67:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0445_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0500_pm = (df.loc[68:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0500_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0515_pm = (df.loc[69:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0515_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0530_pm = (df.loc[70:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0530_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0545_pm = (df.loc[71:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0545_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0600_pm = (df.loc[72:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0600_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0615_pm = (df.loc[73:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0615_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0630_pm = (df.loc[74:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0630_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0645_pm = (df.loc[75:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0645_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0700_pm = (df.loc[76:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0700_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0715_pm = (df.loc[77:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0715_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0730_pm = (df.loc[78:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0730_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0745_pm = (df.loc[79:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0745_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0800_pm = (df.loc[80:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0800_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0815_pm = (df.loc[81:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0815_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0830_pm = (df.loc[82:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0830_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0845_pm = (df.loc[83:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0845_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0900_pm = (df.loc[84:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0900_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0915_pm = (df.loc[85:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0915_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0930_pm = (df.loc[86:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0930_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_0945_pm = (df.loc[87:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_0945_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1000_pm = (df.loc[88:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1000_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1015_pm = (df.loc[89:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1015_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1030_pm = (df.loc[90:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1030_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1045_pm = (df.loc[91:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1045_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1100_pm = (df.loc[92:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1100_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1115_pm = (df.loc[93:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1115_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1130_pm = (df.loc[94:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1130_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)

day1_1145_pm = (df.loc[95:n:per_day*7])
day1 = day1.append(day1_1145_pm.mean(axis = 0, numeric_only = True),ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: If you put the data as text in your question, you are likely to get good answers.

Comment: You have timestamps. It's far safer to `groupby` the date then to hope you're not missing a single row which would ruin every subsequent calculation.

Comment: How would use groupby to select only a set of cells, I don't want the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using groupby function

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

df["FullDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FullDateTime"])
df["DayOfWeek"] = df["FullDateTime"].dt.day_name()
df["Time"] = df["FullDateTime"].dt.time
means = df.groupby(["DayOfWeek", "Time"])["kW"].mean()

means = means.reset_index()

# to get averages of a day
means[means["DayOfWeek"]=="Friday"]
```